# Как найти длину окружности на изображении?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow

[image: пример]Дано изображение необходимо найти длину окружности на нем , пробовал сделать это с помощью opencv-python по координатам , но наверно должен быть способ с помощью tensorflow , суть в том , что дана половина круга на картинке и надо найти длину этой дуги , подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать с помощью встроенных датасетов к примеру может что-то типа нахождения буквы C.

Comment: Покажите примеры входных данных

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Желательно несколько примеров или расскажите словами: фиксировано ли расположение дуги, единственная ли она на картинке, отличается ли цвет дуги от цвета фона и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно, для этого можно использовать `tensorflow` - библиотеку для машинного обучения для Python. Проблема в том, что вам нужно получить очень много подобных изображений уже с ответами. Программа обучится и будет уже выдавать (о точности можно забыть) ответы. Обычная программа вряд ли справится с таким заданием.
Да и машинное обучение будет, на самом деле, эффективно, если вы будете фотографировать объекты на одном расстоянии постоянно.
Проблема заключается в том, что мы даже не знаем какой масштаб изображения. Может эта полуокружность размером с трёхэтажку.
Так что даже настоящему человеку будет не по силам эта задача. Но всё же дерзайте и всё получится!

---

Всем добра-бобра!

Comment: и на этом спасибо!)

Comment: Нейронные сети тут излишни, я бы делал так: бинаризация, нахождение остова, удаление линий, касающихся границ морфологической реконструкцией. Площадь оставшегося остова дуги будет равна длине дуги части эллипса